# Calculating sum of a column in a dataset

Tags: jasper-reports

I have the following query for a dataset:

```sql
select item, sum(salesAmount) as TotalSales from sales
group by item
order by TotalSales desc;
```

and I have set REPORT_COUNT<=5 for limiting the data to 5 records only.

Now I want to display top 5 items through a list component and their Sales Amount in percentage to that of the TotalSales amount of the top 5 items.

I have tried to create a variable in the dataset as

```
sales_sum
class: BigDecimal
Calculation : Sum
Reset Type : Report
Increment Type : None
Variable Expression : $F{TotalSales}
```

But the sales_sum increments with each row in the list. thus gives inaccurate value 
for the percentage. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the evaluation time of sales_sum variable , as I understand this variable is calculating sum row wise i.e for first row sum will be same as TotalSales value then for second row sum will be first value of and second value of TotalSales and so on, so you will be getting 1st % always 100.

To change this Evaluation Time property select the field where you are using sales_sum variable like for sales percentage and go to the property of that field  and change the Evaluation Time property to :-

```
             Evaluation Time    Auto
```

Second solution:-

```
 SELECT a.item,a.TotalSales, (a.TotalSales/a.Total) * 100 as Total_Perc
 FROM
 (select item,
        sum(salesAmount) as TotalSales,
         (select sum(salesAmount) as TotalSales from sales
          order by TotalSales desc
          limit 5) Total
 from sales
 group by item
 order by TotalSales desc
 limit 5) a;
```

Comment: Thanks Sharad for your reply. I tried your suggestion but it is giving null and error in filling report. I am using the List Component in the title band and I haven't specified any group for the dataset. I tried with other evaluation time like Page, Report. But they give same percentage value for all rows.. Can you please suggest some alternetive. Thanks..

Comment: You can also calculate Percentage using query only then you do not need to add variable, I have edited the answer check for the query.

Comment: I can't use the query. Is there no way of this doing in iReport? How it can be done in Dataset